# Is it possible to get m columns after nth column in an SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, I want a query that gets the data from 4 columns after the n column that will be a variable in my code, so when I execute a function GetData(n, rowNum), the query will return the nth, n+1, ..., n+4 columns from the specified row.

Is this do-able?

Image concretising my situation :

[image]

A session is an interaction between two users (or more), I want to send n1 (or n2, ...) and receive n1+1, n1+2, ... after I send the query.

So is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Extra edit : the data for user1 and user2, is nowhere else in the database, all the data is specific to the session. So as far as I know, I have to get it from the session table.

Extra extra edit : I just need a function where I can send n1 (a known number, let's call it 1), and receive the 2 columns after it. 2 and 1 are constants. Which I will then myself modify to suit my needs. I didn't think it was this complicated.

Comment: Your question is really difficult to figure out. Maybe provide an actual example of a table scheme and the result you would like to achieve?

Comment: There is absolutely no reason why you would ever want to do this - unless there was a fundamental flaw in the design of your schema. See normalisation

Comment: How many users are for this table, do you like to normalize it?

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam There are 5 users in this table, and while the users table has some data specific to the user, a session contains some data that is specific to the session (data that is otherwise useless unless the user is in a session, interacting with other users). A session can contain 2 users, with all the 3 remaining userIDs being equal to 0, while if a userID is different from 0, he is considered in the session, and corresponding data is generated in code.

Comment: That can be done sure

Comment: I will do it tomorrow if no one answers. Need sleep

Comment: will the names of the fields always stay the same?

Comment: @davejal yes, and their positions. I think I'm close to finding the corresponding query myself.

Comment: either normalise your schema or dispense with the RDBMS altogether. That's not to say that the problem can't be solved, just that there's no point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this stored procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetData`(IN `n` INT, IN `tbl` VARCHAR(100))
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ', GROUP_CONCAT(c.COLUMN_NAME), ' FROM ',tbl,';')
    INTO @query
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
    WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = tbl
      AND c.ORDINAL_POSITION IN(n,n+1,n+2,n+3)
    ORDER BY c.ORDINAL_POSITION ;

    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;

    EXECUTE stmt;
END
```

Usage sample in Query :

```
CALL `GetData`('4', 'table_name');
```

This is how `4th,5th,6th,7th` col of `table_name` table.

Answer (score 0):

It will be solved via dynamic sql and you can use store procedure to run queries or db function that get user id and then return query to execute.

Similarly [here](http://forumone.com/blog/how-pass-mysql-table-and-column-names-stored-routine-arguments/)